# MySql query optimised in console, but not optimised in Node/Python clients

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, node-mysql

I have a rather complex query, using many joins and a `not in` clause. I've tailored this query using the MySql console to be optimised, and I'm sure there is no `DEPENDEND SUBQUERY` in the execution plan. But, for my surprise, when I execute the *exact same query* in the same MySql instance, using the Node and Python clients, the query is much slower. Using the `explain` statement through such clients, two `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` show up. How come the very same query is successfully optimised when issued directly in the console, but not through such clients? How can I debug this issue?

Edit: requested details.

The output from `SELECT @@optimizer_switch` is the same, from the console and the python client:
`index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on`

The execution plan from the MySql console:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                             | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | c           | NULL       | ALL  | config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key | NULL                | NULL    | NULL | 1912779 |     5.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                                                      | NULL                | NULL    | NULL |  956388 |     1.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  2 | DERIVED     | c           | NULL       | ALL  | config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key | NULL                | NULL    | NULL | 1912779 |    50.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  4 | UNION       | c           | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                                                      | NULL                | NULL    | NULL | 1912779 |    10.00 | Using where                                        |
|  4 | UNION       | <derived7>  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                                                      | NULL                | NULL    | NULL |  956388 |     1.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  4 | UNION       | a           | NULL       | ref  | idx_accounts_domain                                                       | idx_accounts_domain | 202     | func |      26 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                           |
|  9 | SUBQUERY    | c           | NULL       | ALL  | config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key | NULL                | NULL    | NULL | 1912779 |     5.00 | Using where                                        |
|  9 | SUBQUERY    | <derived11> | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                                                      | NULL                | NULL    | NULL |  956388 |     1.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 11 | DERIVED     | c           | NULL       | ALL  | config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key | NULL                | NULL    | NULL | 1912779 |    50.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  7 | DERIVED     | c           | NULL       | ALL  | config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key | NULL                | NULL    | NULL | 1912779 |    50.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

The execution plan, from the python client:

```
[
  (1, 'PRIMARY', 'c', None, 'ALL', 'config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key', None, None, None, 1912779, 5.0, 'Using where'),
  (1, 'PRIMARY', '<derived2>', None, 'ALL', None, None, None, None, 956388, 1.0, 'Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)'),
  (2, 'DERIVED', 'c', None, 'ALL', 'config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key', None, None, None, 1912779, 50.0, 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'),
  (4, 'UNION', 'c', None, 'ALL', None, None, None, None, 1912779, 10.0, 'Using where'),
  (4, 'UNION', '<derived7>', None, 'ALL', None, None, None, None, 956388, 1.0, 'Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)'),
  (4, 'UNION', 'a', None, 'ref', 'idx_report_settings_domain', 'idx_report_settings_domain', '202', 'func', 26, 100.0, 'Using where; Using index'),
  (9, 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'c', None, 'ALL', 'config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key', None, None, None, 1912779, 5.0, 'Using where'),
  (9, 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', '<derived11>', None, 'ALL', None, None, None, None, 956388, 1.0, 'Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)'),
  (11, 'DERIVED', 'c', None, 'ALL', 'config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key', None, None, None, 1912779, 50.0, 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'),
  (7, 'DERIVED', 'c', None, 'ALL', 'config_idx_path2,config_idx_path_key2,config_idx_path,config_idx_path_key', None, None, None, 1912779, 50.0, 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort')
]
```

The query is of the form:

```sql
(
  <<account_report_settings>>
)
union all
(
  select *
  from (
    <<inherited_report_settings>>
  ) as inherited
  where inherited.account not in (
    select direct.account
    from (
      <<account_report_settings>>
    ) as direct
  )
)
```

where `<<account_report_settings>>` and `<<inherited_report_settings>>` are some rather long subqueries. I can provided the full query if necessary, but it's very complex and I don't know if it would be of much help.

Comment: Please run `SELECT @@optimizer_switch` on both sessions. Also, can you share the query and both execution plans?

Comment: @Solarflare I've updated the post with the requested details. Let me know if there is anything else I could provide.